# Prove that a series is $O(t^a)$.

Tags: complex-analysis, asymptotics, self-learning, taylor-expansion

Consider the series
$$ u(t,x) = \sum_{i \geq 1} {u_i(x) t_1^i } + \sum_{i+2j \geq k+2, j\geq 1} {\varphi_{i,j,k}(x) t_1^i t_2^j y^k} $$
where $t \in \tilde{\mathbb{C} \setminus \{ 0 \}}$, $x$ is complex $n$-dimensional, and 
$$t_1 = t, t_2 = t^{\rho(x)}, y = \log t.$$
$\rho (x) $ is some given function, $\log$ is the natural logarithm, and $\tilde{\mathbb{C} \setminus \{ 0 \}}$ is the universal covering space of $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$. Assume that the coefficients are holomorphic on the same disk.

It is known that $u$ converges on the region
$$ \{(t,x) : |t_1| < \epsilon, |t_2 | <\epsilon , |yt_1|<\epsilon, |y^2 t_2| <\epsilon, |x_i| < r\ (i =1,...,n) \}.$$

I want to show that 
$$ \max_{x \in K} |u(t,x)| = O(t^a)$$
as $t$ tends to zero in $S_\theta := \{t : |\arg t|<\theta \}.$

**What I have so far:** Take $r_1 > 0, r_2 > 0, r_3 > 0,$ and $r_4 > 0$ so that $r_1 < \epsilon, r_2 < \epsilon, r_3 r_1 < \epsilon, r_3^2 r_2 <\epsilon$ and $r_4 < r$ hold. Then $u$ is now convergent on the region
$$ \{(t_1, t_2 , x, y) : |t_1| \leq r_1 , |t_2| \leq r_2, |y| \leq r_3, |x_i| \leq r_4\ (i=1,...,n) \}.$$
We can get Cauchy's estimates for the coefficients as follows: For some $M$,
$$ |u_i (x) | \leq \dfrac{M}{r_1^i} \qquad \text{and} \qquad |\varphi_{i,j,k} (x) | \leq \dfrac{M}{r_1^i r_2^j r_3^k}$$
on $D(r_4) := \{x : |x_i| \leq r_4\ (i=1,...,n) \}.$

---

There, any help - hints, suggestions on how to proceed, results that can be used - would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Just wondering: from where is this function? PDE?

Comment: Yes, PDE. It's the form of a family of solutions of a nonlinear PDE.

Comment: This sounds like a job for the substitution $t \rightarrow r \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\psi}$.  Then you're taking a limit as $r \rightarrow 0$ with $-\theta <\psi < \theta$.  $t_1^i \rightarrow O(r^i)$, $y \rightarrow O(\log t) < O(t)$.  Assuming $\rho$ is real-valued, $t_2^j \rightarrow O(r^{j \rho(x)})$.  Hope this helps.  I don't see how to finish without some promise that the $\varphi$ go to zero fast enough.